# Vídeo Full screen como background para qualquer resolução

Tags: css, css3

Preciso colocar um vídeo em full screen como background de uma página web, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aceita tb vídeo.ogg e vídeo.webm**

> O WebM vem sido utilizado para reproduzir arquivos de vídeo em páginas HTML5 sem que para isso seja exigido que os usuários instalem plugins adicionais no navegador. É um formato que cada vez mais deve ser utilizado por sites da internet.

CSS

```
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="vide.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>

 <p><font size="7" color="#FF0000">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing."</font></p>
```

> Atributos loop muted autoplay  [navegadores compatíveis](https://developer.jwplayer.com/articles/html5-report/tag-attributes-and-apis/autoplay-loop-muted.html)

Formatos de mídia suportados por elementos HTML de áudio e vídeo e Compatibilidade de navegadores [Compatibilidade de navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/formatos_midia_suportados#Compatibilidade_de_navegadores)

Comment: Perfeito Leo! Obrigado!